# Why the JVM's Runtime max memory is smaller than the value specified in command line -Xmx?

Tags: java

I start my program by specifying the max memory to 128MB

```
java -Xmx128M ...
```

Then I connect to the jvm instance with jconsole. In the "VM Summary" tab, I found that:

```
Maximum heap size: 127,808 kbytes
```

This value is smaller than the one I specified in command line. Can any one give me some tips on this?

Comment: Have you tried lower-case m instead of an M?

Comment: Maybe some megabyte to kilobyte conversion magic... Have you tried to set it by kilobyte (`k` or `K`)?

Answer (score 2):

I checked the value that is reported by [Java Visual VM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html). It is exactly what I configured as JVM argument:

**Example**

```
JVM argument: 1024m
Heap Max: 1.073.741.824 B
```

So I guess jconsole has a special kind of calculation or Java Visual VM adjusts the value to the configured JVM argument - who knows?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the exact memory size to be slightly smaller.  How much smaller apepars to vary based on the version of Java and the OS.  I suspect there is some implementation reasons why its is not precisely what you asked for.

BTW: This is only the maximum of the heap size.  There are many other memory areas e.g. thread stack, direct memory, perm gen, shared libraries, native resources and memory mapped files which are not included so I wouldn't woory too much about it i.e. as there is a good margin of error between this value and the maximum memory the application will use.

BTW2: A maximum of 128m is rather small these days. Is there a good reason for it to be so small?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your comment and suggestion! But I'm still not convinced. I think there must be some more "official" explain.

Comment: I would be interested to read it if there is one. I suspect they consider it too small to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the following [Java bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4391499):

> Not a bug.  The interpretation of the -Xmx flag is VM-dependent.  Some
> VMs, including HotSpot, enforce a lower bound on the effective value
> of this option. The CCC proposal should not have mentioned the -Xmx
> flag in this way.